# Как объявить переменную DataFrame, когда заранее неизвестно количество столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas

```
fin_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['DATE',0,1,2,3])#Объявили пустой датафрейм куда запишем окончательные данные. КОЛИЧЕСТВО СТОЛБЦОВ ЗАВИСИТ ОТ КОЛИЧЕСТВА КАНАЛОВ СТАНЦИИ!!!  
    for every in list_of_paths: #Открываем каждый часовой файл в текущей суточной директории

        df=pd.read_csv(every, header=None, sep=' ') 
        df['DATE']=df[1].str.cat(df[2], sep=' ') #Соединяем два столбца со временем чтобы получить дату в нужном формате
        cols = [0, 'DATE',3] #Выбираем нужные столбцы и расставляем их в нужном порядке
        df = df[cols] #Переопределяем датафрейм столбец 0-номера каналов, 'DATE'-дата, 3-номер столбца с отчетами
        date_fl=df.loc[0,'DATE'] # Дата начала отсчета в файле. Будет использоваться как время в строке осредненного файла
        df1=df.groupby(df[0])[cols].mean() # Осредняем данные со 100Гц до одной минуты. Файл длительнотью записи 1 минута.
        temp_df=df1.T   #Временный датафрейм приводим к удобному виду. Транспонируем, теперь номера каналов это имена столбцов, данные в строках
        temp_df=temp_df.drop(index=[0]).reset_index() #Удаляем первую строчку с мусором и сбрасываем индекс
        temp_df.loc[0,'DATE']=date_fl # Подставляем дату в столбец временного датафрейм
        cols_for_temp_df=['DATE',0,1,2,3] #Определяем порядок столбцов
        temp_df=temp_df[cols_for_temp_df] #Переставляем столбцы местами
        fin_df=fin_df.append(temp_df[['DATE',0,1,2,3]]) #Дописываем данные файла в итоговый df
```

Это часть скрипта, которая получает на вход список файлов и в цикле создает из них один датафрейм нужного вида. Проблема в следующем: для того, чтобы соединить данные файлов в один датафрейм (fin_df) необходимо заранее знать количество столбцов (это номера каналов аналогово-цифрового преобразователя, АЦП) в нем. Иногда, в поступаемых файлах количество строк (число каналов АЦП), может отличаться в большую или меньшую сторону. Данные каналов извлекаются из строк с помощью  df1=df.groupby (строки данных группируются по каналам), где они осредняются, затем df1 транспонируется (строки данных становятся столбцами, номера каналов именами столбцов). В таком виде они добавляются в fin_df (append). Заранее прочитывать весь список поступаемых файлов (количество файлов сотни тысяч) на предмет определения количества используемых каналов нерационально с точки зрения машинного времени. Скрипт и без того работает долго. Наверняка существует способ обойти проблему с объявлением  fin_df с фиксированным количеством столбцов. Надеюсь понятно описал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Наверняка существует способ обойти проблему с объявлением fin_df с
> фиксированным количеством столбцов.

Разумеется. Добавить столбец в существующий датафрейм можно так:

```
 df['Channel_5']=['q', 'w', 'r']
```

Здесь мы добавили столбец 'Channel_5' и значениями в этом столбце будут q w r.